# how to see the output for each iteration/step in for loop when debugging

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested for loop in which I need to see the output at each iteration for debugging purposes. How can I achieve this?

Here is the example code for which I need to see what the output is.

```
for sheet_name, df in Input_Data.items():
    for line in df:
        if line.startswith('Linear'):
            index = line.index('Linear')
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for sheet_name, df in Input_Data.items():
    for line in df:

        print(line) # just print the line

        if line.startswith('Linear'):
            index = line.index('Linear')      

            break
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.